# Is cart destroyed or not in example in Agile Web Development with Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am recently following Agile book to iteration E3. In this iteration, I could "successfully" empty cart with correct view and passed test as tutorial showed. However, in rails'console, when I check `Cart.all`, corresponding cart still exists; when I force to http://localhost:3000/carts/1; I saw all previous selected line items still exist. I thought when the destroy is invoked, cart and corresponding line-item should be destroyed from database but it seems not. Where did I misunderstand? Could someone explain why this happaned? I pushed my source code into github: https://github.com/WeiliangXing/depot-rails.git
Also I found session[:card_id] is equal to nil, which is supposed to have something because I use set_cart method in LineItemController to set current_cart session. Can someone help me to figure out why?

Comment: Could you clarify what exactly you did? Did you run the test, then rails c => Cart.all ?That would open the console in development environment, but your deleted cart is in test.

Comment: I run test, it passed; I also ran the application in chrome and did empty cart operation (there is a empty button in /carts/1), which showed the cart is successfully emptied and back to root; however, after this operation, when I typed address /carts/1, it shows the cart and its items still exist. Also I use console to check whether there are carts after above operations, and yes it is still there. I cannot explain why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very specific question and I think, if you just kept going through your tutorial, you might have found the answer yourself :)

The reason why your cart ist still there, is because it does not get deleted.
There is a guard that says "if @cart.id == session[:id]" which never returns true, because session[:id] is nil.

At some point in your app, you have to set the session[:id], I THINK, this should be in `def create; ...; end` but I did not read the tutorial, so I don't want to point you in a wrong direction.

The reason your test still passe is: You set the session[:id] in your test, but never in your actual application.

So, a lot more interesting for you is maybe how to debug a rails application:

['puts' is very usefull](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/IO.html#method-i-puts) it will write stuff in your console.
So, I did this:

```
# DELETE /carts/1
# DELETE /carts/1.json
def destroy
  puts @cart.id, session[:cart_id].inspect, @cart.id.to_s == session[:cart_id]

  @cart.destroy if @cart.id == session[:cart_id]
  session[:cart_id] = nil

  respond_to do |format|
  f  ormat.html { redirect_to store_url, notice: 'Your cart is currently empty.' }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  end
end
```

Which gave me the output

```
1
nil
false
```

Use puts to find out what your application is doing, and use .inspect to make sure things like "nil" will be written out and not just be empty space.

Happy Coding :)

Comment: Just curious why session[:cart_id] is nil? because I use set_cart method in before_action already of LineItemController, which is defined in concerns/current_cart.rb to set the session value. When I click an item to add; the session should have records.

Comment: I just started to type out a huge "how to avoid that kind of problem tutorial", but honestly, I don't think you need that, because you're allready doing a tutorial.
You provided a fallback for the case no cart exists, so everytime no cart exists, the will be a new one created. Did you change the tutorial code, because I can't believe the tutorial would tell you to do that...

Comment: I followed that code in tutorial strictly. Do you mean that tutorial provides a bad code?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem(. In my case the *puts* provided by @Ninigi outputs the next:

```
11
11
false
```

Then I've deleted *to_s* method from *@cart.id.to_s == session[:cart_id]* and get

```
11
11
true
```

But the issue wasn't fixed, of cource. And I thought that the

```
@cart.destroy if @cart.id == session[:cart_id]
```

is a recursion and I've changed *destroy* method to *delete*. Now this row looks as:

```
@cart.delete if @cart.id == session[:cart_id]
```

And a magic did own work) Now we can to destroy a cart without a error.

I hope it helps anybody.

Thanks!